Python argparse parse_known_args(namespace=); use of namespace?
Trying to understand pymol-open-source  setup.py, I came accross this use of
argparse.parse_know_args() namespace keyword:
import argparse
...

class options:
    osx_frameworks = True
    jobs = int(os.getenv('JOBS', 0))
    no_libxml = False
    no_glut = True
    use_msgpackc = 'guess'
    testing = False
    openvr = False
    use_openmp = 'no' if MAC else 'yes'
    use_vtkm = 'no'
    vmd_plugins = True
...

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--glut', dest='no_glut', action="store_false",
                    help="link with GLUT (legacy GUI)")
parser.add_argument('--no-osx-frameworks', dest='osx_frameworks',
                    help="on MacOS use XQuartz instead of native frameworks",
                    action="store_false")
parser.add_argument('--jobs', '-j', type=int, help="for parallel builds "
                    "(defaults to number of processors)")
parser.add_argument('--no-libxml', action="store_true",
                    help="skip libxml2 dependency, disables COLLADA export")
parser.add_argument('--use-openmp', choices=('yes', 'no'),
                    help="Use OpenMP")
parser.add_argument('--use-vtkm', choices=('1.5', '1.6', '1.7', 'no'),
                    help="Use VTK-m for isosurface generation")
parser.add_argument('--use-msgpackc', choices=('c++11', 'c', 'guess', 'no'),
                    help="c++11: use msgpack-c header-only library; c: link against "
                    "shared library; no: disable fast MMTF load support")
parser.add_argument('--testing', action="store_true",
                    help="Build C-level tests")
parser.add_argument('--openvr', dest='openvr', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('--no-vmd-plugins', dest='vmd_plugins',
                    action='store_false',
                    help='Disable VMD molfile plugins (libnetcdf dependency)')
options, sys.argv[1:] = parser.parse_known_args(namespace=options)
...

where in options, sys.argv[1:] = parser.parse_known_args(namespace=options), the
namespace points to the options class.
I guess it is used to filter sysy.argv to be passed to setuptools.setup?
Is it the preferred / pythonic / correct way to use
parser.parse_known_args namespace?
Usually namespace type returns <class 'argparse.Namespace'>  while using this.
I got <class '__main__.Namespace'>.
Is this behaviour documented for argparse, do namespace keywords accept other kind of objects which could be useful to navigate pre-setup options?
Please bear with me, not expert in  Python, setptools, and argparse.

Not my downvote, but  this is rather unclear. Please review the [help] and in particular How to ask as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

what is unclear. I was asking if its correct to pass a class object as namespace keyword in argparser.pares_know_args?  Or if its correct in python to store values as class attributes , I believe if am not wrong that is not considered good python programming. -And was wondering why namespace accepts it and if could accept other objects like dictionary and so on

theree is no error in code of course

I can see three distinct questions, one of which appears vague (what exactly is "this task"?) and two of which seem like secondary follow-ups ("is this documented" and "are there others" which stretches into too-broad territory). Please focus on a single, well-defined question. Probably explain in more detail what's going on and which aspect of it you need help with.

Is it the preferred / pythonic / correct way to use
parser.parse_known_args namespace ?

You can use your own class instead of the default Namespace, if you have some reason to. I'm surprised you're supposedly seeing <class '__main__.Namespace'> with your code, I'd have expected __main__.options. Are you sure this is a representive outcome? Is that perhaps your question? Besides that, should you use your own class? If you don't have a reason, no. If you do, yes.

.... Usually namespace type returns <class 'argparse.Namespace'> while using this... I was not referring to this example . If I use options, sys.argv[1:] = parser.parse_known_args(namespace=options) ; type(options) is Namespace. A little bit up .... where in options, sys.argv[1:] = parser.parse_known_args(namespace=options), the namespace points to the options class.---> __main__.options

Basically, this is using an instance of type instead of an instance of argparse.Namespace to hold defined arguments. It's a bit unorthodox, in that it defines a class with no intention of instantiating the class.

Perhaps a more orthodox approach would be to use the set_defaults method to provide default values for the various arguments, rather than initializing options or an instance of Namespace manually.

The use of a namespace keyword parameter, and the default Namespace class is documented, https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.Namespace

thanks @hpaulj , it says more:  It may also be useful to have an ArgumentParser assign attributes to an already existing object, rather than a new Namespace object. This can be achieved by specifying the namespace= keyword argument: parser.parse_args(args=['--foo', 'BAR'], namespace=c)
c.foo
'BAR'

@hjpaulj never encountered that before (my inexperience/lack of experiece fault) everything was about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694284/python-should-i-put-my-data-in-lists-or-object-attributes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694284/python-should-i-put-my-data-in-lists-or-object-attributes, I'll google more / try to read documentation  better

All the parser does with the namespace instance is fetch and set attributes, with basic setattr etc.  All the default class adds is a prettier display of the attributes.

Yes, normally one would simply use the default behavior of parse_known_args creating an instance of argparse.Namespace to store the results, and using the set_defaults method to provide default values. Something like
import argparse

[...]



parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
[...]
parser.set_defaults(osx_frameworks=True,
                    jobs=int(os.getenv('JOBS', 0)),
                    no_libxml=False,
                    # etc)

options, sys.argv[1:] = parser.parse_known_args()

The author of this library chose instead to use a class (an instance of type) instead of an instance of Namespace to store the arguments, and to  initialize the class attributes with their default values.
(Note, too, one could specify defaults for each argument in the appropriate call to add_argument. set_defaults is useful for initializing targets that might be set by multiple arguments, or that are only conditionally created after parsing.)

just to be sure  I am getting it right default argvs are treated like known args by by parser.parse_known_args() ?

Defaults for a target are used when the target is not otherwise set by a call to parse_known_args.

Here just to try to add relevant code to accepted answer,
using parser.set_default():
import argparse

import os

import sys

WIN = sys.platform.startswith('win')
MAC = sys.platform.startswith('darwin')

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)


parser.set_defaults(osx_frameworks = True,
    jobs = int(os.getenv('JOBS', 0)),
    no_libxml = False,
    no_glut = True,
    use_msgpackc = 'guess',
    testing = False,
    openvr = False,
    use_openmp = 'no' if MAC else 'yes',
    use_vtkm = 'no',
    vmd_plugins = True)

parser.add_argument('--glut', dest='no_glut', action="store_false",
                    help="link with GLUT (legacy GUI)")
parser.add_argument('--no-osx-frameworks', dest='osx_frameworks',
                    help="on MacOS use XQuartz instead of native frameworks",
                    action="store_false")
parser.add_argument('--jobs', '-j', type=int, help="for parallel builds "
                    "(defaults to number of processors)")
parser.add_argument('--no-libxml', action="store_true",
                    help="skip libxml2 dependency, disables COLLADA export")
parser.add_argument('--use-openmp', choices=('yes', 'no'),
                    help="Use OpenMP")
parser.add_argument('--use-vtkm', choices=('1.5', '1.6', '1.7', 'no'),
                    help="Use VTK-m for isosurface generation")
parser.add_argument('--use-msgpackc', choices=('c++11', 'c', 'guess', 'no'),
                    help="c++11: use msgpack-c header-only library; c: link against "
                    "shared library; no: disable fast MMTF load support")
parser.add_argument('--testing', action="store_true",
                    help="Build C-level tests")
parser.add_argument('--openvr', dest='openvr', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('--no-vmd-plugins', dest='vmd_plugins',
                    action='store_false',
                    help='Disable VMD molfile plugins (libnetcdf dependency)')




options , sys.argv[1:] = parser.parse_known_args()

print('options : ', options )


print('sys.argv[1:] : ',sys.argv[1:])


print('type(options)  :', type(options), options)

for i in dir(options):
    
    if not i.startswith('_'):
        
        try:
   
            print(i ,    '   -----  ' , getattr(options, i) )
            
        except:
            
            print(i, 'errorrrrrrrrr')



print('\n\n\n')

d = vars(options)

print(d)


print('no_glut :',options.no_glut)
print('jobs : ', options.jobs)

or default keyword in parser.add_argument:
import argparse

import os

import sys

WIN = sys.platform.startswith('win')
MAC = sys.platform.startswith('darwin')



parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)



parser.add_argument('--glut', dest='no_glut', action="store_false", default= True,
                    help="link with GLUT (legacy GUI)")
parser.add_argument('--no-osx-frameworks', dest='osx_frameworks', default=  True  ,
                    help="on MacOS use XQuartz instead of native frameworks",
                    action="store_false")
parser.add_argument('--jobs', '-j', type=int, default=  int(os.getenv('JOBS', 0)), help="for parallel builds "
                    "(defaults to number of processors)")
parser.add_argument('--no-libxml', action="store_true", default=  False ,
                    help="skip libxml2 dependency, disables COLLADA export")
parser.add_argument('--use-openmp', choices=('yes', 'no'), default=   'no' if MAC else 'yes',
                    help="Use OpenMP")
parser.add_argument('--use-vtkm', choices=('1.5', '1.6', '1.7', 'no'), default=  'no' ,
                    help="Use VTK-m for isosurface generation")
parser.add_argument('--use-msgpackc', choices=('c++11', 'c', 'guess', 'no'), default=  'guess' ,
                    help="c++11: use msgpack-c header-only library; c: link against "
                    "shared library; no: disable fast MMTF load support")
parser.add_argument('--testing', action="store_true", default=  False ,
                    help="Build C-level tests")
parser.add_argument('--openvr', dest='openvr', action='store_true', default= False)
parser.add_argument('--no-vmd-plugins', dest='vmd_plugins',
                    action='store_false', default=  True ,
                    help='Disable VMD molfile plugins (libnetcdf dependency)')


options , sys.argv[1:] = parser.parse_known_args()


print('options : ', options )


print('sys.argv[1:] : ',sys.argv[1:])


print('type(options)  :', type(options), options)

for i in dir(options):
    
    if not i.startswith('_'):
        
        try:
   
            print(i ,    '   -----  ' , getattr(options, i) )
            
        except:
            
            print(i, 'errorrrrrrrrr')


print('\n\n--------------------------------')


d = vars(options)

print(d)


print('no_glut :',options.no_glut)
print('jobs : ', options.jobs)

using argparser.Namespace to store the setup.py options, sure the options are more difficult to be read in the code than in the original library where a class was used to store them.
Use of parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter) adds default values description to --help
